# Values are not being populated into the dictionary <string, string> while I am iterating over a string[] to acquire the <key, value> pair

Tags: c#, dictionary

My idea is to populate a dictionary with string as as key and string as value.
Where x = base64EncodedString of some file that lives in a directory and y = This represents the file name along with the extention so, fileName.extension

I am iterating over a bunch of files that live within a local directory and acquiring the base64string, along with the filename.extension of each file. 
In the process I check to see if the value already exists for a given key, and if it does exist, I DO NOT add the key value pair, otherwise I populate the dictionary.

Here is my code below, I am a beginner, and I am trying to work this out.

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string[] attachmentPaths = Directory.GetFiles("someLocalFilePathPopulatedWithFiles");
Byte[] attachmentBytes;
string base64EncodedString;
string attachmentFileName;

foreach (string attachment in attachmentPaths)
{
  //Base 64 conversion process
  attachmentBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(attachment);
  base64EncodedString = Convert.ToBase64String(attachmentBytes);
  attachmentFileName = Path.GetFileName(attachment);

  if (d.TryGetValue(base64EncodedString, out attachmentFileName))
  {
    Console.WriteLine("exists");
    //trying to get a value for a key that does not exist, on the first iteration, then the compiler jumps to the else{}
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("!exists");
    //Since the <key, value> does not exist, go ahead and populate the dictionary
    d.Add(base64EncodedString, attachmentFileName);
  }
}

//Print out the key value pair.
//The value is not being printed.
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in d)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Key: " + pair.Key + " " + "Value: " + pair.Value);
}
```

The issue is that the value is not being printed.

I have also tried this with simpler code to test the logic and it seemed to work. This seems to work as in I am able to populate the dictionary object with the data that I want, and in the process checking to see if it already exists.

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
d.Add("B", "fileB");
d.Add("C", "fileC");
d.Add("D", "fileD");
////we have an empty dicitonary, so lets try to get the value of key that IS not part of dictionary
string val = "fileA";

if (d.TryGetValue("A", out val))
{
  Console.WriteLine("exists");
  //do not add a key, since the <key ,value> exists
  //so the compiler will always jump to the else, {adding a <key, value>}
}
else
{
 Console.WriteLine("!exists");
 d.Add("A", "fileA");
}
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in d)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Key: " + pair.Key + " " + "Value: " + pair.Value);
}
```

I am convinced that there is a difference, but I do not seem to catch it because I am still trying to learn.

Comment: Set breakpoints and step through your code. My guess is that the path is pointing to an empty directory.

Comment: Is the dictionary totally empty after the `for` completes? or does it have only one `<key, value>`pair?

Comment: What are the files in the directory?   Which ones are missing from the dictionary when you run your code?

Comment: Instead of TryGetValue() try using ContainsKey().  It will make the code less busy I think.  And your assignment into the dictionary could be d[key] = value.

Comment: d.TryGetValue(base64EncodedString, out attachmentFileName)). This line will clearout the attachmentFileName if it not exists, so in your else part you are adding only null. you need to use another variable here to test if it exists.

Comment: The directory is not empty. It contains files of different extensions, and I am able to print out the key, and value when I remove the try.getValue part of my code.

Comment: @Thangadurai - Can you provide some sort of sample code.
I see that you want me to use a temp value to check the existence, what would the value be for var temp = ?.

Comment: @SumanthMaddirala I have posted it as answer. see below

Answer (score 1):

d.TryGetValue(base64EncodedString, out attachmentFileName)). This line will clearout the attachmentFileName if it not exists, so in your else part you are adding only null. you need to use another variable here to test if it exists.
Use some temp variable to check the existence

```
foreach (string attachment in attachmentPaths)
{
  //Base 64 conversion process
  attachmentBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(attachment);
  base64EncodedString = Convert.ToBase64String(attachmentBytes);
  attachmentFileName = Path.GetFileName(attachment);
  var filename=string.Empty;

  if (d.TryGetValue(base64EncodedString, out filename))
  {
    Console.WriteLine("exists");
    //trying to get a value for a key that does not exist, on the first iteration, then the compiler jumps to the else{}
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("!exists");
    //Since the <key, value> does not exist, go ahead and populate the dictionary
    d.Add(base64EncodedString, attachmentFileName);
  }
}

//Print out the key value pair.
//The value is not being printed.
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in d)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Key: " + pair.Key + " " + "Value: " + pair.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Complete rewrite after comment by OP.

If the point is to find files where the content is a duplicate of the contents of a different file, then the answer by @Thangadurai should be enough to get past you immediate problem.

I would still suggest that you calculate a digest/hash of the contents of each file, then use a base 64 encoded version of that as you dictionary key. That way you don't have to store the whole content of each and every file in memory while your method is running. Something like this (only very quickly tested):

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string[] attachmentPaths = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\temp");

System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed sha1 = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed();
byte[] oneFileHash = null;

foreach (string attachment in attachmentPaths)
{
    using (FileStream oneFileStream = File.OpenRead(attachment))
    {
        oneFileHash = sha1.ComputeHash(oneFileStream);
    }
    if (oneFileHash == null)
        continue;

    string base64EncodedHash = Convert.ToBase64String(oneFileHash);
    string attachmentFileName = Path.GetFileName(attachment);

    if (d.ContainsKey(base64EncodedHash))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("exists");
        //trying to get a value for a key that does not exist, on the first iteration, then the compiler jumps to the else{}
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("!exists");
        //Since the <key, value> does not exist, go ahead and populate the dictionary
        d.Add(base64EncodedHash, attachmentFileName);
    }
}

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in d)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: " + pair.Key + " " + "Value: " + pair.Value);
}
```

If I were you I would not waste any thought on the relative performance of `ContainsKey` and `TryGetValue`. Neither of them will be the bottleneck here. If you want to check if the dictionary contains a certain key already, go ahead and use the method that most clearly signals that it's doing that for you.

**Note**: There is a theoretical chance that two files with different contents will end up with the same hash. The chance that this will happen is vanishingly small. So small that you can in practise ignore it completely...

Comment: I am not using fileName as a key on purpose because this is a part of a process where attachments are being download from an email and uploaded to our ticketing system.
x.txt and x(1).txt can have the same base64String, and when people send attachments, there might be duplicate attachments with different file names.
I am trying to avoid uploading duplicate attachments.
As for the containsKey() - I read that it is slower and requires more hash lookups vs tryGetValue().
I want our opinion on what might be more apt in my case.
Thanks